# xcode 8 Detected missing constraints

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

every time when i start my macOS app, i get this message:

> 2017-05-29 09:55:02.232005+0200 App[14423:1257408] [Layout] Detected
>   missing constraints for <_NSSplitViewItemViewWrapper: 0x6080001a1c00>.
>   It cannot be placed because there are not enough constraints to fully
>   define the size and origin. Add the missing constraints, or set
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be
>   generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12
>   and later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your
>   override. Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug.
>   This error will only be logged once.

how can i solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on `DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS` to debug.

Comment: and how will i do this?

Comment: i created a symbolic breakpoint like the picture in my first post. is it correct like this?